# How to plot subplots of line chart with 3 features

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot subplots from this dataframe.

df:

```
cOne:    cTwo:      cThree:     Date:    
car      blue        other     2006-06-12 15:00:00
truck    yellow      other2    2004-05-19 17:00:00
car      red         other3    2012-05-28 09:00:00
```

I want to plot an individual sub-plot for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday...Sunday). The x-axis should be each hour of the day. While the lines should represent 'cOne', the y-axis being the counts of the occurrences for each 'cOne' for the respective hour and day.

Thanks.

Comment: According to the description you want 7 subplots, each with two lines in it fro the two categories from `cOne`. But what is the role of `cTwo` and `cThree` in that case. I guess it makes sense to clearly describe the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish is to use [`pandas.DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) to extract the day of week from the `datetimes` and use that along with an array of the options you are interested in (i.e. `['car', 'truck']) to accumulate the occurrence for each hour within each day over the date range. Here is an example which demonstrates this approach (using some randomly generated data for demonstration)

```
week = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
opts   = [['car', 'truck'],
         ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'],
         ['other', 'other2', 'other3']]
dates = pd.date_range('01-01-2000', '01-01-2001', freq='H')
cOne = list()
cTwo = list()
cThree = list()
n = len(dates)
for ii in range(n):
    cOne.append(opts[0][np.random.randint(0,2)])
    cTwo.append(opts[1][np.random.randint(0,3)])
    cThree.append(opts[2][np.random.randint(0,3)])

df = pd.DataFrame({'cOne': cOne,
                  'cTwo': cTwo,
                  'cThree': cThree,
                  'Date': dates})
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])))
hours = df.index.hour
columnsTitles=["Date", "cOne", "cTwo", "cThree"]
df=df.reindex(columns=columnsTitles)

x = pd.date_range('00:00', '23:00', freq = 'H')
x = range(0,24,1)
rows = len(df.index)
col = df.columns
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(21,3*(len(col)-1)))
fig.suptitle("Hourly Occurence by Day of Week", y = 1)
for mm in range(1, len(col)):
    for ii in range(len(week)):
        y = [[0]*len(x) for i in range(len(opts[mm-1]))]
        for jj in range(rows):
            if dates[jj].dayofweek == ii:
                for kk in range(len(opts[mm-1])):
                    if df[col[mm]][jj] == opts[mm-1][kk]:
                        y[kk][hours[jj]] = y[kk][hours[jj]] + 1
                        break
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(col)-1, len(week), ii + (mm - 1)*(len(week)) + 1)
        if mm == 1:
            ax.set_title(week[ii])
        for ll in range(len(opts[mm-1])):
            ax.plot(x, y[ll], linewidth=1, linestyle='-', alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

The output of which is 
[image: Hourly Occurrence by Day of Week]